# How to get the value from a resolved promise

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am new to Angular and having hard time to understand how to get the value from a resolved promise. I used $q.all([element1.$promise, e2.$promise]). I got the element1 which is a json object. For, element2 which is a scalar containing 2.0. I tried element[1] just like element[0] but it contains no property, so I don't know how to get the value. I tried .val, .data, etc. I know both the web api and angular are getting 2.0.

```
              resolve: {
            accountResource: "accountResource",
            account: function(accountResource, $stateParams, $q) {

              var info = accountResource.get({ accountId: $stateParams.accountId });
              var currentBalance = accountResource.getCurrentBalance({ accountId: $stateParams.accountId });

              return $q.all([info.$promise, currentBalance.$promise]);
            }

    vm.account = account[0];
    vm.currentBalance = account[1];
```

resource function

```
    function accountResource($resource) {
    var webApiUrl = "https://localhost:44301";
    return $resource(webApiUrl + '/api/account/:accountId', {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET'
        },          
        query: {
            method: 'GET', 
            isArray: true, 
            url: webApiUrl + '/api/account/search/:queryMethod/:queryString'
        },
        getCurrentBalance: {
            method: 'GET', 
            url: webApiUrl + '/api/account/getcurrentbalance/:accountId'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In the same way as you get a value from an unresolved promise.

Comment: What is that `account` thing you are accessing?

Comment: It's just a value, not a property, it's just the parameter, no need to `.val` it or anything like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `$q.all` likes this (with dictionary instead of array):

```
return $q.all({info: info.$promise, currentBalance: currentBalance.$promise})
```

And after that get information in this way:

```
vm.account = account.info;
vm.currentBalance = account.currentBalance;
```

Try to rewrite your resource as this:

```
function accountResource($resource) {
var webApiUrl = "https://localhost:44301";
// Add second parameter {accountId: "@accountId"}
return $resource(webApiUrl + '/api/account/:accountId', {accountId: "@accountId"}, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET'
    },          
    query: {
        method: 'GET', 
        isArray: true, 
        url: webApiUrl + '/api/account/search/:queryMethod/:queryString'
    },
    getCurrentBalance: {
        method: 'GET', 
        url: webApiUrl + '/api/account/getcurrentbalance/:accountId'
    }
});

}
```

---

**Updated**

You can add `transformResponse` property to your `getCurrentBalance` function in `accountResoure`. And transform your value from API to json format.

```
getCurrentBalance: {
    method: 'GET', 
    url: webApiUrl + '/api/account/getcurrentbalance/:accountId',
    transformResponse: function (balanceFromApi) { 
        return { balance: balanceFromApi }; 
    }
}
```

And finally you can get information, likes this:

```
vm.account = account.info;
vm.currentBalance = account.balance;
```

I tested it with `$httpBackend` service and everything is fine now. Hope this helps.

Comment: I do like dictionary better than array. But it does not solve then problem. account.currentBalance does not contain any property. account.currentBalance =>
e {$promise: Promise, $resolved: true, toJSON: function, $get: function, $save: function…}

Comment: Can you please show your function getCurrentBalance from accountResource?

Comment: No, it should not have anything to do with the resource as it is returning a value "2.0". I just don't have a property to reference to, like the info. info.BillingAddress1. currentBalance itself is another promise. I don't think I need to change my web api to return {balance: currentBalance}. But I know that should work. But not currentBalance by itself.

Comment: Oh, now I see. The simplest way is just return json from your back end, which is similar to your version {balance: 2.0}. I think, that it's a good practice. I can think about other approaches a little bit later. %)

Comment: Thanks. I know that there is something that I am missing, transformResponse.